# How to see policies for S3 buckets which showing `Access Denied` error in AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've logged into AWS account as root user. But I'm unable to access some of the buckets in AWS. They are not showing in the S3 Console. I've accessed them by submitting the bucket name in the url 
**For example let's call the bucket unaccessible-bucket**
`https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/unaccessible-bucket/?region=us-east-1&tab=overview`
If I navigates to `Permissions > Bucket Policy` I'm seeing notice `Access denied`, I'm unable to download the files. I'm unable to change the policy. I've tried with AWS CLI also.
Can someone please tell me how to edit the policy. 
As per our organisation requirement,
We have to add two new IAM users..
For one user...We have to grant access to all buckets including this `unaccessible-bucket`.
For other user...We have to grant access to only this `unaccessible-bucket`.
[Please check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp91e.png)
Many Thanks.

Comment: Does the S3 console list the buckets? If so and you are denied access to the bucket contents or policies, then that suggests that a bucket policy may have been applied denying you access. If the S3 console does not list the buckets then they are likely in a different AWS account (which would explain why you cannot access them).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are logged into the AWS Console as the root user.

If you cannot see an S3 bucket in the AWS console, then you do not own the bucket and it is owned by another account.

If you can see the bucket in the console then you own the bucket. If you cannot access the contents of the bucket then you will need to edit the S3 Bucket Policy and add the root user as a principal. Replace the account number with your own.

Add this statement (or modify) to your S3 Bucket Policy:

```
"Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root" }
```

Comment: I'm getting `Access denied` error if I try to add anything in the bucket policy.

Comment: Edit your question and include the policy.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this. I'm unable to see the existing policy and I'm unable to  add `"Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root" }` as policy. I can write data into the bucket, I can read the data what I've written. That's it. 
Now I want to delete the existing policy and I want to get full access to the bucket.

Comment: Please check this Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp91e.png. This is what I'm getting if I navigates to `Permissions > Bucket Policy`. I've tried deleting the bucket policy with `aws s3api delete-bucket-policy --bucket unaccessible-bucket` Still same error `Access Denied`

Comment: Are you double sure that you are logged in with Root credentials and not some other IAM user? The reason that I ask is that you cannot deny the root user access to IAM policies and roles. Using the AWS CLI, list the buckets and double check ownership, etc. for this bucket. The root user can deny himself access to an object or service, but the root user can always give it back to the root user.

Comment: Yes I logged in as root user. I'm double sure about this. I believe that this `unaccessible-bucket` is accessed by only one IAM user. That IAM user account is deleted. What shall we do now?

Comment: In the AWS Console, select your bucket. Can you go to the tab "Access Control List"? Check the ACL permissions if you can. You might have the option "Write Bucket Permissions" disabled.

Comment: What happens if you run this command: "aws s3api put-bucket-acl --acl private --bucket <bucketname>. If this succeeds go back into the console and see if you have access.

Comment: Also try: "aws s3api put-bucket-acl --grant-full-control --bucket <bucketname>